# Insert child UI component inside existing one

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have 2 modules where each one has an `UI component` on frontend. *Module A* contains the main component and component of *Module B* should be displayed inside the component of module A. I'm not instantiating components via `XML` and `jsLayout` but directly from `.phtml` file.

**Module A**

`Module/A/view/frontend/templates/main.phtml`

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'module-a-main'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "module-a-main": {
                        "component": "Module_A/js/view/main"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`Module/A/view/frontend/web/js/view/main.js`

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'uiComponent'],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults : {
                template: 'Module_A/main'
            },
            childText: 'It works!'
        });
    }
);
```

`Module/A/view/frontend/web/template/main.html`

```
<h1>Main component title</h1>
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('test_region') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

**Module B**

`Module/B/view/frontend/templates/child.phtml`

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'module-b-child'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "module-b-child": {
                        "component": "Module_B/js/view/child"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`Module/B/view/frontend/web/js/view/child.js`

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'uiComponent'],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults : {
                template: 'Module_B/child'
            }
        });
    }
);
```

`Module/B/view/frontend/web/template/child.html`

```
<p data-bind: text: childText></p>
```

The structure above currently just creates two `UI components` which are not aware of each other.

How should I structure both of them so component of Module A can display child component(s) inside a `region` (test_region) or similar other way and share the data to it's children?

The end `HTML` output should be:

```
<h1>Main component title</h1>
<p>It works!</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using structure via `XML` and `jsLayout` as explained [in this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324971/94427).